# Breadcrumb for lightning-tree

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a lightining-tree component for Role Hierarchy. This is the item:

```
<!-- ROLE TREEVIEW -->
<lightning-tree items={items} onselect={handleSelectAssign}></lightning-tree>
<!-- END ROLE TREEVIEW -->
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]

And now I need to implement a breadcrumb when a Role is clicked, showing the hierarchy  of the selected role at this breadcrumb. Is it possible?

Best regards,
Renato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a simple recursive function. I wrote a [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/FJOggFQ71emTL5CCErrZ/src/app.js?p=stories) for you.

```
  handleSelect(event) {
    // Used to find a node recursively
    const find = (path, node, name) => {
      // This is the node we wanted, return the final array here
      if(node.name === name) {
        return [...path, node];
      }
      // There are children to search through
      if(node.items) {
        // For each child, try to find a matching child, 
        // returns 0 if none found, which will go to parent's next child
        return node.items.reduce((prev, item) => {
          return prev || find([...path, node], item, name)
        }, 0);
      }
    }
    this.breadcrumbs = find([], { items: this.items }, event.detail.name).slice(1);
  }
```

Comment: Amazing! It works perfectly! Thank you very much!